# A solution to replace all whitespaces with a character inside a pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to apply the following steps:

- find everything starts after **="** and ends before **"**
- fill all the whitespaces with **<>** in between that pattern and leave other whitespaces as they are

My python script looks like this:

```
string = 'machine="machine m45" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"' 

matches = re.findall(r'="(.+)"', string) 
for m in matches:
  text = m.replace(' ', '<>')
  string = re.sub(m, text, string)
print(string)
```

String remains the same on my output.

What I want to have is:

```
machine="machine<>m45" level=info msg="Daemon<>has<>completed<>initialization"
```

Could you please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'="[^"]*"', lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+', '<>', x.group()), string)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast solution! @WiktorStribiżew